# soft question: comparison of differential geometry textbooks

Tags: book-recommendation

So I really want to do well in my differential geometry course next semester, the professor is the one that I want to do research with eventually.

Furthermore, santa is bringing me Do Carmo's "differential geometry of curves and surfaces" for xmas, but since I know Jesus is real and Santa isn't i'm sure my mother will give it to me as soon as I get back home for the holidays. Will this text be adequate for a standard graduate level introduction to the topic? I hear that if you are really serious about differential geometry spivak is the only way to go, am I correct in my thinking that that may be overkill for my purposes? I mean Spivak is broken up into five volumes, so yeah, seems like a bit much.

Thanks!

Comment: do carmo is good for a basic/undergraduate introduction. im not really sure what "graduate level introduction" means. you should know diff geo before grad school...

Comment: The drek in your question about  your beliefs in Jesus and Santa is deeply irritating. Please let's stick to mathematical reality on MSE.

Comment: @RobArthan What's wrong with a little sense of humor? I really enjoyed it.

Answer (score 1):

Forget Spivak .The best book for readability at the graduate level is by William M Boothby -An introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry .